# latent dirichlet allocation how to deal with words not in the vocabulary

Tags: c++, text-mining

For latent dirichlet allocation, since it assumes a fixed vocabulary bag (I obtained with tf-idf method), how can we deal with words not in the words bag, say those stopwords?

Do we still consider such words take a position in the document(in other words, are we supposed to assign topics to these words) or just ignore those words?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this problem arises because your corpus on which you trained LDA to obtain topic vectors doesn't have the words that you found in the test documents (brought into the experiment later for getting their topic break up). If this is the case then ignoring the new words is ok if your corpus has a large number of words e.g. if it is an english corpus then a vocabulary size of 100,000+ words would be considered large enough.

On the other hand, if above is not the case and these new words are the ones that will distinguish one document from another then you are better advised to run your LDA by including these words in the training set.